# View XML file on network drive

Tags: xml, network-drive

I want to view an XML file on a network drive.
When I open it with notepad it works fine.
But when i try with Internet explorer ( the xml file has a layout) i get the   following result:

```
De XML-pagina kan niet worden weergegeven     
Kan XML-invoer niet lezen met opmaakmodel XSL. Herstel de fout en klik vervolgens op de knop Vernieuwen of probeer het later opnieuw.        
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Toegang geweigerd.
```

Translated:

```
The XML page can not be displayed    
Can not read XML input with XSL style sheet . Restore the error and then click  
the Refresh button , or try again later.      
-------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------
Access denied.
```

When i copy the file to a local directory everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give it a try in some other browser as well. I think you have some security settings in IE that does not allow you to access the XSL.

Comment: Looks like antivirus can also be a cause. Check this link once http://forums.netobjects.com/showthread.php?1887-The-XML-Page-Cannot-Be-Displayed

Comment: you can also give a try to whats mentioned in the link below https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7bce3991-e0ba-4f48-9d26-e9294439caf8/the-xml-page-cannot-be-displayed?forum=w7itprogeneral